# Nginx pass_proxy subdirectory without url decoding

Tags: nginx

I need to write an nginx location directive to proxy requests to subdirectory to another server **preserving urlencoding** and **removing subdirectory prefix**.

Here's an artificial example — request like this:

```
http://1.2.3.4/api/save/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
```

should pass as

```
http://abcd.com/save/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
```

I tried several different ways. Here're couple of them:

1. From [this SO question](https://serverfault.com/a/379679/181546)

   ```
    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api(/.*) $1 break;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_pass http://abcd.com;
    }
   ```

But it decodes the string, so `http://abcd.com` gets `/save/http://example.com`

2. From [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20544409/1224211)

   ```
    location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_pass http://abcd.com;
    }
   ```

But it keeps subdirectory, so `http://abcd.com` gets `/api/save/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`.

What's needed is somewhere in the middle. Thank you!

**UPD: Here's a [ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/727) in nginx bug tracker**

Comment: You could try something with lua. But first of all you shoulld not need this, as per http spec these urls are identical

Comment: Or use subdomain instead of subdirectory

Comment: @AlexeyTen The server running on the `http://abcd.com` is processing those requests in different way and I haven't control over it. Do you know a link to that http spec excerpt? I cannot find it

Comment: RFC 2616 section 3.2.3

Comment: @AlexeyTen It says _Characters other than those in the "reserved" and "unsafe" sets (see RFC 2396 [42]) are equivalent to their ""%" HEX HEX" encoding._ I don't know what is `[42]` in the RFC 2396, but section 2.2 in that RFC says that those characters are reserved — `";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","`

Comment: Well, I admit you're right, I've missed that part. But there is no easy way to fix this nginx behaviour. There are some bugs in nginx trac, you could add yours. http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/query?status=accepted&status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&summary=~uri&order=priority.

So, I think that the simplest way is to have subdomain.

Comment: @rinat.io, ping.  Is there anything missing from my answer?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, actually, there is!  See my answer, if you're still interested!

Comment: @cnst it's good as a brain training, but for real production OP better should fix backend

Comment: @AlexeyTen as I said in the ticket comment it doesn't seem like decoding works according to RFC (I'm not sure though), so I don't understand what might be wrong with backend.

Comment: @cnst, unfortunately I cannot check your answer now since I don't use that backend these days.

Comment: @rinat.io, but my answer does include a complete test setup with two separate servers, where it can be reproduced which directions do and do not result in the encoding being decoded; thanks for the upvote, but I'd appreciate an accept as well. :-)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I agree with rinat, there is nothing that needs to be fixed in the backend (nor in nginx itself, btw).  Decoding by default is a good usability and security feature of nginx; but disabling said decoding can also be beneficial for some test cases such as these.

Answer (score 83):

> > > But there is no easy way to fix this nginx behaviour. There are some bugs in nginx trac, you could add yours. trac.nginx.org/nginx/…. So, I think that the simplest way is to have subdomain. – Alexey Ten Feb 24 '15 at 14:49
> >
> > https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/727
>
> If you want nginx to do something custom, you can do so using ​proxy_pass with variables (and the $request_uri variable, which contains original unescaped request URI as sent by a client). In this case it will be your responsibility to do correct URI transformations. Note though that this can easily cause security issues and should be done with care.

Challenge accepted!

```
    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) $1 break;
        return 400;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82/$uri;
    }
```

That's it, folks!

---

Here's for the full proof.

The config file for `nginx/1.2.1`:

```
server {
    listen 81;
    #first, the solution
    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) $1 break;
        return 400; #if the second rewrite won't match
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82/$uri;
    }
    #next, a few control groups
    location /dec/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82/;
    }
    location /mec/ {
        rewrite ^/mec(/.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
    }
    location /nod/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
    }
}

server {
    listen 82;
    return 200 $request_uri\n;
}
```

Here are the results of running the queries for each location:

```
% echo localhost:81/{api,dec,mec,nod}/save/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com | xargs -n1 curl
/save/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
/save/http:/example.com
/save/http:/example.com
/nod/save/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
%
```

Note that having that extra `return 400;` is quite important — otherwise, you risk having a security issue (file access through `//api` etc), as Maxim has briefly mentioned in your trac ticket.

---

P.S. If you think using the rewrite engine as a finite-state automaton is super cool, you might also want check out my http://mdoc.su/ project, or [fork it github](https://github.com/cnst/mdoc.su).

Comment: To avoid `the rewritten URI has a zero length` errors, I have used

    rewrite ^ $request_uri;
    rewrite ^/api(/.*) $1 break;
    return 400;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82$uri;

Comment: I'm wondering if something has changed in later nginx versions. Try as I might, with nginx 1.13.12 and this approach any URL encoding present in the original request_uri (e.g. %2F) instead of decoding gets encoded again (so becomes %252F)

Comment: To comment on my comment - I was trying to do a rewrite for a redirect but it seems it's impossible to defeat the re-encoding there, and instead you need to extract the parts of the URL and then use a return instead.

Comment: It would be worth adding in the answer an explanation why `//api` matches the `location` block. It is because "_The matching is performed against a normalized URI, after decoding the text encoded in the “%XX” form, resolving references to relative path components “.” and “..”, and possible compression of two or more adjacent slashes into a single slash._" as stated in [location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation. And compression being enabled by default - see [merge_slashes](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes)

Comment: With this solution, I'm getting this error:

`proxy      | 2024/02/05 13:14:45 [error] 20#20: *1 no resolver defined to resolve index, client: 172.26.0.1, server: index.torrust-demo.com, request: "GET /api/v1/proxy/image/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Ftorrust%2Ftorrust-index%2Fdevelop%2Fdocs%2Fmedia%2Ftorrust_logo.png HTTP/1.1", host: "index.torrust-demo.com"`

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/786?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2 says you have to use a resolver.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is fairly easy as long as we are talking prefix matching with `^~` or no modifier

```
location /api/ {
  # if you don't want to pass /api/ add a trailing slash to the proxy_pass
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;

  ...
}
```

And everything will be passed along without decoding, you don't have to pass `$uri`

Also while you use proxy pass you should also set these headers

```
# pass headers and body along
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_pass_request_body on;

# set some headers to make sure the reverse proxy is passing along everything necessary
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: "everything will be passed" : True, until you replace `localhost` upstream with a variable.

Comment: Permission to kick myself. So simple! *facepalms* ‍♀️ I actually had precisely the reverse issue — making sure that the full path is passed. Who'd guess that a trailing slash would make that much of a difference... thanks, your answer saved me hours and hours of debugging!

Comment: I don't think this is true. Nginx doesn't decode the query string, but it still appears to decode the URI when I use this method.  I've verified the accepted answer does not decode URI.