# Reverse image proxy without specifying host

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following in my config as a reverse proxy for images:

```
location ~ ^/image/(.+) {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/$1;
}
```

The problem is that not all images will be example.com images and so we need to pass in the full url. If I try:

```
location ~ ^/image/(.+) {
    proxy_pass $1;
}
```

I get an error:

```
invalid URL prefix in "https:/somethingelse.com/someimage.png"
```

Comment: what is the url that you will be using when it points to some other domain else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is quite vague, but, based on the error message, what you're trying to do is perform a `proxy_pass` entirely based on the user input, by using the complete URL specified after the `/image/` prefix of the URI.

Basically, this is a very bad idea, as you're opening yourself to become an open proxy.  However, the reason it doesn't work as in the conf you supplied is due to URL normalisation, which, in your case, compacts `http://example` into `http:/example` (double slash becomes single), which is different in the context of `proxy_pass`.

If you don't care about security, you can just change [`merge_slashes`](http://nginx.org/r/merge_slashes) from the default of `on` to `off`:

```
merge_slashes off;
location …
```

Another possibility is to somewhat related to [nginx proxy_pass and URL decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995818/nginx-proxy-pass-and-url-decoding)

```
location ~ ^/image/.+ {
    rewrite ^ $request_uri;
    rewrite ^/image/(.*) $1 break;
    return 400;
    proxy_pass $uri; # will result in an open-proxy, don't try at home
}
```

The proper solution would be to implement a whitelist, possibly with the help of `map` or even prefix-based location directives:

```
location ~ ^/image/(http):/(upload.example.org)/(.*) {
    proxy_pass $1://$2/$3;
}
```

Do note that, as per the explanation in the begginning, the location above is subject to the `merge_slash` setting, so, it'll never have the double `//` by default, hence the need to add the double `//` manually at the `proxy_pass` stage.

Comment: That's a good point re:open proxy. I plan on making sure it is an image (eg ends in .png, .jpg, etc). Also implement the secure link module as described here https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2016/05/25/caching-resizing-reverse-proxying-image-server-nginx. Will those methods be enough to make it ok to use in production?

Comment: @kristen The `Content-Type` response header tells you the MIME type of the content being served; not sure how DDG does it, I presume they have a bit more logic than just nginx.conf. :-)  TBH, if I were to block one filetype from an open proxy, images would probably be it, so, whitelisting the images hardly adds any protection.  Using [`secure_link`](http://nginx.org/r/secure_link) might address security concerns, but only if the whole logic is implemented correctly (e.g., to only generate the links based on input from trusted users).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map in this case

```
map $request_uri  $proxied_url {
   # if you don't care about domain and file extension
   ~*/image/(https?)://?(.*)   $1://$2;

   # if you want to limit file extension
   ~*/image/(https?)://?(.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|ico))$   $1://$2;
   # if you want to limit file extension and domain

   ~*/image/(https?)://?(abc\.xyz\.com/)(.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|ico))$   $1://$2$3;
   default "/404";
}
```

Then in your proxy pass part you would use something like below

```
location /image/ {
   proxy_pass $proxied_url;
}
```

I have given three different example depending how you want to handle it