# RabbitMQ nginx config

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq, centos7

I have problem that entering RabbitMQ management page in server it asks on each requests basic auth login. I cannot resolve it so that i have not enter on each request.
Here is my nginx config:

```
location ~* /rabbitmq/api/(.*?)/(.*) {
    #rewrite         ^/rabbitmq/api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/$1/%2F/$2?$query_string;
    allow all;
}

location ~* /rabbitmq/(.*) {
    rewrite         ^/rabbitmq/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:15672;
    allow all;
}
```

Version:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.11.2
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584637/23118) is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

When asking for assistance, it helps people if you provide **complete** configuration files rather than just a snippet as you have done.

This is a complete configuration that redirects `localhost:8888/rabbitmq` to the management server running on port `15672`. I have tested it with `nginx` `1.14.0` and RabbitMQ `3.7.6`. I am only prompted to log in once. I ran it as my normal user with this command:

```
nginx -p /home/lbakken/issues/SO/rabbitmq-nginx-config-48881248 -c nginx.conf
```

```
user                 lbakken lbakken;
worker_processes     1;
# Note: for debugging, very useful
# error_log            /dev/stderr debug;
error_log            /dev/stderr;
pid                  nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;
daemon               off;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx;
    fastcgi_temp_path     /tmp/nginx;
    scgi_temp_path        /tmp/nginx;
    uwsgi_temp_path       /tmp/nginx;
    proxy_temp_path       /tmp/nginx;
    access_log            /dev/stdout;

    upstream rabbitmq {
        least_conn;
        server localhost:15672 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
        listen                          8888;
        server_name                     127.0.0.1;

        # Note: a big thanks to this answer:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584637
        location /rabbitmq/api/ {
            rewrite ^ $request_uri;
            rewrite ^/rabbitmq/api/(.*) /api/$1 break;
            return 400;
            proxy_pass http://rabbitmq$uri;
        }

        location /rabbitmq {
            rewrite ^/rabbitmq$ /rabbitmq/ permanent;
            rewrite ^/rabbitmq/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://rabbitmq;
            proxy_buffering                    off;
            proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The gist link is dead.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for noticing.