# RabbitMQ Management Over HTTPS and Nginx

Tags: nginx, https, rabbitmq

I'm trying to access the RabbitMQ interface over HTTPS/SSL with nginx, and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Here's my rabbitmq.conf file:

```
[
  {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']}]},
  {rabbit, [
      {reverse_dns_lookups, true},
      {hipe_compile, true},
      {tcp_listeners, [5672]},
      {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
      {ssl_options, [
        {cacertfile, "/etc/ssl/certs/CA.pem"},
        {certfile,   "/etc/nginx/ssl/my_domain.crt"},
        {keyfile,    "/etc/nginx/ssl/my_domain.key"},
        {versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']}
      ]}
    ]
  },
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {listener, [
      {port, 15671},
      {ssl,  true},
      {ssl_opts, [
        {cacertfile, "/etc/ssl/certs/CA.pem"},
        {certfile,   "/etc/nginx/ssl/my_domain.crt"},
        {keyfile,    "/etc/nginx/ssl/my_domain.key"},
        {versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}
].
```

All works ok when I restart rabbitmq-server

My nginx file looks like this:

```
location /rabbitmq/ {
        if ($request_uri ~* "/rabbitmq/(.*)") {
                proxy_pass https://example.com:15671/$1;
        }
}
```

Now, I'm guessing there's something with the ngnix config not being able to resolve the HTTPS URL, as I'm getting 504 timeout errors when trying to browse:

```
https://example.com/rabbitmq/
```

**Obviously, this is not the correct FQDN, but the SSL cert works fine without the /rabbitmq/**

Has anyone been able to use the RabbitMQ Management web interface on an external connection over a FQDN and HTTPS?

Do I need to create a new "server" block in nginx config dedicated to the 15671 port?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I ended up reverting back to the default rabbitmq.config file, then modified my nginx config block to the below, based on another stackoverflow answer that I can't find right now.

```
    location ~* /rabbitmq/api/(.*?)/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/$1/%2F/$2?$query_string;
        proxy_buffering                    off;
        proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~* /rabbitmq/(.*) {
        rewrite ^/rabbitmq/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15672;
        proxy_buffering                    off;
        proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Also, I had browser caching for JS files, which was causing issues and have disabled that.

I will try to re-enable SSL piece-by-piece but do have the example URL working for now:

```
https://example.com/rabbitmq/
```

Comment: This got me most of the way, but I'm getting a bunch of ``Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`` errors from js files, and I've tried both disabling and clearing my cache... did you ever find the core issue with the JS files and how to fix it?

Comment: I removed the .js extension from nginx caching.

Comment: You saved me tons of time here. I only modified the target to another server behind a firewall and it worked perfectly. Just remember to add the "/" at the end of the URL in your browser.

Comment: Awesome David, glad it helped!

Comment: Thank you Dario. It works for some of the APIs like `queue` or `exchange`. But not with `user` API which doesn't need `%2F` as a vhost

Comment: I got also the users API part working by removing the first location configuration. It only matched the users API management like `rabbitmq/api/users/my-username` and broke it. All other API calls were already going through the second location configuration. Tested with https://github.com/nginxinc/NGINX-Demos/tree/master/nginx-regex-tester .

Comment: Thanks, this rule `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/$1/%2F/$2?$query_string;` worked for me, but seems like a hack. Should be easier.

Answer (score 23):

I tried the following nginx.conf

```
    location /rabbitmq/ {
        proxy_pass http://rabbitmq/;
        proxy_buffering                    off;
        proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

However I couldn't get the details for a `queue` or `exchange`. I got 404 errors for api calls.
And there was a `%2F` in the url, it's url encoded `/`.

We need to keep the `%2F` in the API url and pass it to rabbitmq.

The following link describes how to keep the encoded url part and rewrite it.
[Nginx pass_proxy subdirectory without url decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684300/nginx-pass-proxy-subdirectory-without-url-decoding/37584637#37584637)

So my solution is:

```
    location /rabbitmq/api/ {
        rewrite ^ $request_uri;
        rewrite ^/rabbitmq/api/(.*) /api/$1 break;
        return 400;
        proxy_pass http://rabbitmq$uri;
        proxy_buffering                    off;
        proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /rabbitmq/ {
        proxy_pass http://rabbitmq/;
        proxy_buffering                    off;
        proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Comment: Bingo, I tried 5 variants of this but this one did it.

Comment: This was the best solution.

Comment: An other solution to prevent url decoding is to use $request_uri: 

`location ^~ /rabbitmq/ {  if ($request_uri ~* "/rabbitmq/(.*)") { proxy_pass http://rabbitmq_server/$1; }}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, i was trying to fix it in the wrong way (single rewrite!), this trick made it work!

Answer (score 9):

This did the trick for me

```
location /rabbitmq {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:15672/;
  rewrite ^/rabbitmq/(.*)$ /$1 break;
}
```

I didn't have to use any other directives.

Comment: This answer again proves that copying lots of configuration is dangerous sometimes. This answer ended my 2 days debugging and searching for answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for the solution for the Apache (2.4):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName              rabbitmq.your-domain.com
        AllowEncodedSlashes     NoDecode 
        ... // rest of the settings

        <Location "/">
          Require all granted
          
          ProxyPass         http://localhost:15672/
          ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:15672/
        </Location>
        <Location "/api">
          Require all granted

          ProxyPass         http://localhost:15672/api nocanon
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

In fact, 2 elements are very important:

1. The 'AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode' on VirtualHost level
2. The 'nocanon' parameter for ProxyPass on "/api" location

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and I did not need any other header settings. This is a variation on the answer by @user3142747:

```
location /rabbitmq/ {
    # Strip off the "/rabbitmq" prefix
    rewrite  ^/rabbitmq/(.*) /$1 break;

    # Do NOT suffix proxy_pass path with a trailing "/". This allows NGINX to pass the client request completely unchanged.
    #    - see http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2009-November/016577.html
    proxy_pass $scheme://localhost:15672;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be a little bit late but RabbitMQ have a subpath config and you can easily set it with [Path Prefix](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#path-prefix)

Here is a docker compose exposed RabbitMQ behind Nginx proxy:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    hostname: 'rmq'
    image: rabbitmq:management
    container_name: 'rmq'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rmq-usr
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=burFPso0ULwPMp_w3lkg4QT6-a2H6
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "127.0.0.1:15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

**rabbitmq.conf** file:

```
management.path_prefix = /rmq
```

and Nginx **server.conf** block:

```
upstream rmq {
  server 127.0.0.1:15672 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;
  error_page 497 https://example.com$request_uri;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.key;
  location /rmq {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rmq;
    allow my.trusted.ip.addresses1;
    allow my.trusted.ip.addresses2;
    deny all;
  }
}
```