# Getting It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken on Jenkins

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins

I 've setup Jenkins server which is running as a docker container behind Nginx reverse proxy, it is served at example.com/jenkins/, everything is working fine except getting "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error on "manage Jenkins page". I would be grateful if anyone can help.

**Docker compose file**

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    environment:
      JENKINS_OPTS: "--prefix=/jenkins"
    ports:
      - 9292:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

**Nginx conf file**

```
   location /jenkins/ {

        proxy_set_header    Host                $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server  $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_pass      http://localhost:9292;
        proxy_redirect  http://localhost:9292/ /jenkins/;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy redirect seems off here as you don't have to remap /jenkins context. Here is a simple config that worked for me in the past.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.ycr.com;

    location /jenkins {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ http://jenkins.ycr.com/;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried your suggestion, but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the url that is in **Manage jenkins > Configure system** to the new url you are using , for your case it is example.com/jenkins/, that should make the error go away.

Comment: Already did that.

Answer (score 0):

Posting also here for all who have the same problem. The error "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" while everything else seems to work can be caused by the nginx configuration and more specifically, by the way [urldecodes proxied links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684300/nginx-pass-proxy-subdirectory-without-url-decoding/37584637#37584637).

In this case the reason is the line

```
   location /jenkins/ {
```

If you really need the ending slash, please see the link above on how to disable urldecoding.

So the Nginx conf file should be as following code:

```
location /jenkins {
    set $diy_connection_upgrade "upgrade";
    if ( $http_upgrade = '' ) {
        set $diy_connection_upgrade "close";
    }

    if ( $http_upgrade = 'keep-alive' ) {
        set $diy_connection_upgrade $http_upgrade;
    }

    proxy_set_header Connection $diy_connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9292$request_uri;
}
```